# Android: getView method of custom adapter not called

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I've searched through a lot of other answer for the same problem, but didn't found any solution that works for me. The problem, as the title says, is that the getView method from my custom adapter doesn't get called.

Here's the code (first the fragment):

```
public class CategoryListFragment extends ListFragment
                            implements NewCategoryDialogListener {

private GestoreAttivitaDbHelper mDbHelper;
private CategoryListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);        

    mAdapter = new CategoryListAdapter(getActivity());
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    CategoryLoader categoryLoader = new CategoryLoader();

    if (mDbHelper == null) {
        mDbHelper = new GestoreAttivitaDbHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    mAdapter.addAll(categoryLoader.getAllCategories(db));
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mAdapter.getCount();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list, container);
}
```

Here's the adapter:

```
public class CategoryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CategoryElement> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CategoryListAdapter(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, R.layout.category_element);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view;

    Log.d("Adapter", "Restituisco la view per l'elemento");

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_element, null);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    //((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_element_text)).setText(getItem(position).getName());
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_element_text);
    textView.setText(getItem(position).getName());

    return view;
}
```

}

And here's my two layout files:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/category_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >  

</ListView>
```

and:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/category_element"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_element_text" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />    

</LinearLayout>
```

I thought that setting the adapter in the onCreate could be a problem, since it is called before onCreateView, and at that time the fragment isn't already associated with the ListView. So I moved the code from the onCreate to the onStart method, but nothing changed.

Also, the getCount() correctly returns me 6, the precise number of element red from the database.

Any help would be really appreciated!!
Thanks.

***Edit:***
Solved!
Problem was in the activity, I had the following code:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(0, categoryListFragment);
```

that I changed in

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_main, categoryListFragment);
```

Without specifying the View id to which the fragment should be attached it never draws it!
In addition, I had to change from this

```
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_element, parent);
```

to this:

```
view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_element, null);
```

in the getView method.
PS. I'm editing this cause I can't answer my own question until 8 hours have passed..

Comment: did you find anything in logcat related to your adapter ?

Comment: it could be that your adapter is in fact loading but there's no content being returned to load your adapter `TextViews`. perhaps you can check or log if the `getItem(position)` actually returns anything. Otherwise, you could just require your "items" to be passed through the constructor and expose them as a field in the adapter like conventionally done.

Comment: I can't find anything in logcat. I also tried put a getItem right after the getCount, and it returns me the right CategoryElement object...

Comment: Is it possible that `CategoryListFragment.onCreateView` interferes with `CategoryListAdapter.getView`? This is probably a silly comment, I'm just brainstorming.

Comment: Don't know, but I doubt it. However I just noticed that container in onCreateView is always null. Could that be the problem? I'm trying to search something about, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `R.layout.category_list` file you need to give the ListView the following attribute:

`android:id="@android:id/list"`

ListFragment (and ListActivity) look for this id to find the `ListView` when you call methods like `setListAdapter()`.

Also, if all you want is a ListView, you don't have to supply a layout file. Simply do not override onCreateView() and the system will provide a `ListView` for you automatically. Only if you want a custom layout do you need to inflate one, and if you do, the ListView should have the id stated above.

Comment: I don't think that matters. In fact I made it work without specifying anything like that in my layout. Thanks anyway!